# Generate a system of linear differential equations from a coefficient matrix

Tags: differential-equations, string-manipulation, expression-construction

I want to generate a system of linear equations that is stable. For that I generated random coefficients and divided the 10 by 10 matrix by the largest eigenvalue and set the diagonal to -1:

```
  coeff={{-1., 0.150176, 0.0923103, 0.128731, 0.0603593, 0.181206, 0.154218, 
  0.181129, 0.183904, 0.0233792}, {0.150176, -1., 0.177743, 0.0363893,
   0.107509, 0.130683, 0.139527, 0.0864388, 0.142071, 
  0.0764704}, {0.0923103, 0.177743, -1., 0.0232546, 0.193606, 
  0.0888027, 0.0706979, 0.0414401, 0.189166, 0.108903}, {0.128731, 
  0.0363893, 0.0232546, -1., 0.0137908, 0.0513826, 0.164665, 0.192096,
   0.131068, 0.0269444}, {0.0603593, 0.107509, 0.193606, 
  0.0137908, -1., 0.0883905, 0.050653, 0.0422616, 0.130421, 
  0.0790802}, {0.181206, 0.130683, 0.0888027, 0.0513826, 
  0.0883905, -1., 0.109839, 0.0830945, 0.115235, 
  0.0673009}, {0.154218, 0.139527, 0.0706979, 0.164665, 0.050653, 
  0.109839, -1., 0.000702345, 0.203273, 0.187426}, {0.181129, 
  0.0864388, 0.0414401, 0.192096, 0.0422616, 0.0830945, 
  0.000702345, -1., 0.158302, 0.190119}, {0.183904, 0.142071, 
  0.189166, 0.131068, 0.130421, 0.115235, 0.203273, 0.158302, -1., 
  0.0200016}, {0.0233792, 0.0764704, 0.108903, 0.0269444, 0.0790802, 
  0.0673009, 0.187426, 0.190119, 0.0200016, -1.}}
```

The eigenvalues are:

```
{-1.42454, -1.24002, -1.21288, -1.18743, -1.12673, -1.03778, \
-1.00059, -0.94649, -0.823552, -3.43571*10^-17}
```

so the system is stable. Now I want to generate equations from that to simulate the system's reaction to some input. Specifically, the above values should be the coefficients of some variables `y1[t]` to `y10[t]` that will be the input to `DSolve` along with some initial conditions.e.g. `y1[0]==1`. That will be 10 equations with 10 variables each. I tried to build all the equations by using strings and turning them into expressions, but this somehow did not work very well since `ToExpression` messes up the order and values of the variables.

Does anybody have an idea how to do this and give me an example?

Comment: Use `y[i,t]` (or `y[i][t]`) instead of `yi[t]` so you don't have to mess with strings. Then you just need `coeff.Table[y[i,t],{i,10}]==b` to get your equations.

Comment: Thanks for the hint! I'm not sure I understand entirely. Somehow I have to add `y'[i,t]==` in front each equation in order to use `DSolve`. Also, I have to somehow append the initial conditions `y[i,0]==0' asf. Not sure how to do that with your approach. Can you maybe give a full working example?

Comment: `y[t_]=Table[y[i,t],{i,10}]; DSolve[coeff.y[t]==y'[t],y[t],t]` You might want to check out `Scope->Systems of Differential Equations->Solve a system of ODE's in vector format` in the docs for `DSolve`

Comment: That works very well, thank you! Quick final question though: How do I add a vector of initial conditions to this?  E.g. `y[0]==1` and all other variables are 0.